# Incorrect rendering in Chrome fix

Tags: css, google-chrome, media-queries

I've built an app that uses twitter bootstrap.

The nav bar is displayed correctly in Firefox but not in chrome.

I have searched for any bit of code that I code paste to help but I haven't found anything that would be useful so unfortunately all I can do is a link to the [page](http://pozzy.herokuapp.com/signin)

For some reason the slogan is dropping to the next line in chrome. I've tried clear: both and overflow: hidden but nothing seems to work.

The slogan jumps back to the correct position when I use a smaller screen so it might have something to do with a media query.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `.navbar-text` class for that in Bootstrap, but you should put the slogan into the `.navbar-collapse` class.

```
<span class="navbar-text">Private voting platform</span>
```

No need to add extra css.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's always hard to debug something when there's a bootstrap class I haven't heard about.

Answer (score 0):

`.navbar-header` should have width provided or `white-space: nowrap` style set. Now it is wrapping.